# How to disable activating multiple items in uiscrollview with exclusivetouch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

Might be small problem but I am not able solve the issue. Target platform is iOS6.

Problem Description: I have a view controller and one Scroll view as a sub view. In scroll view I have a grid of thumbnails. When i tried to touch multiple thumbnails at a time all thumbnails are activated.

Solution tried:

```
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
self.view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

This is not solving my problem. Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: have you tried to set the exclusiveTouch to the thumbnail instead of to the view?

Comment: Hi Mat thanks for your reply. I tried exclusive touch for individual thumbnail and even for scroll view. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem lies in 2 concepts. 
(1) Make the scrollview synchronize processing of the touch events.

```
self.view.scrollview.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
self.view.scrollview.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Now this will avoid race condition but after first touch is processed 2nd touch will get processed.

(2) To avoid this sequential handling of the touches, I need mutual exclusion to avoid race condition.

- I used a member boolean flag in scrollview and a delegate.
- Now as soon as first first touch processed i am setting the flag to YES. Now when second touch try to get processed I am checking this flag (like mutual exclusion).
- My case is to ignore 2nd touch event as I am navigating to next viewcontroller with first touch. You can process according to your need.

Hope this helps to some other people who are facing this kind of problem..